# transparent background color in PDFView no more working from Mac Catalyst 13.0+

Tags: swift, macos-catalina, apple-pdfkit, mac-catalyst

In a MacOS app, I was using a classic PDFView with a transparent background with a simple:

```
  pdfViewer.backgroundColor = .clear
```

All was working like a charm in Mojave but from the Catalina update I really can fix it. Perhaps it is a bug in relation to Catalyst that could be fixed in the next update but if you see a fix or an alternative it could nice! 
I tried to do a `pdfViewer.removeFromSuperview()` but the windows is well transparent.

Comment: I'm seeing this behaviour on macOS 10.15 in an older AppKit app as well.

Comment: Thanks @Aderstedt nothing to do I think perhaps impossible to do :(